# Issue with loading gltf component generated by gltfjsx package in react

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

After I made the model into a component using gltfjsx I got this error and it’s been pain

Uncaught TypeError : cannot read properties of undefined (reading length) at object.update

I’ve tried regenerating the model with an older version of gltfjsx